# Laravel Blade Form, is it possible to create a textbox input if a user selects the 'other' option?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

This may not be possible with blade, but I was wondering how to generate a textbox input from an 'other' option in a select dropdown. Is this possible?

```
{{ Form::select('showType', array(
     'Theater' => 'Theater', 
     'Club' => 'Club',
     'Festival' => 'Festival',
     'Arena' => 'Arena',
     'Closed Show' => 'Closed Show',
     'College Show' => 'College Show'
     'Other' => 'some kind of text input appears instead'
  )}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use javascript to do that, Blade can't help much. But you can create, in Blade, your form input and set a `hidden` class to it and, when your user select the 'other' option you just have to remove that class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript to do this because it happens on the client side. PHP and Laravel and Blade all happens on the server. An simple jQuery example:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  $('body').append("<input type='text' value='whatever'/>");
});
```